# Android - dialog.setOnKeyListener return falls through

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

So I´m currently trying to fix so that the phone´s backbutton doesn´t close my dialog but for some reason the return statement is unused and it falls through. Does anyone know what I´m doing wrong?

The code:

```
        dialog?.setOnKeyListener { dialog, keyCode, event ->

        if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            true //The expression is unused
        }

        if (event.keyCode == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            true //The expression is unused
        }

        false
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just set `setCancelable` to false?

Comment: I still want to be able to cancel it but it seems like I needed return@setOnKeyListener true instead of just true.

Comment: You can override `onBackPressed` (if there is a `ProgressDialog`, dismiss it; otherwise, do nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Inside this lambda you need to call return@setOnKeyListener to return or you may wrap everything in a if else if ladder and write the last false inside the else statement or use a when and use false as default case